# Getting linux webcam state via command line or API

Tags: linux, command-line, camera

I would, preferably, like to know of a command I can run that will let me know whether a webcam is on/off or recording/not recording, etc. Maybe a way to see if any programs are currently accessing it would work as well. If there is no command line option, I'm not opposed to writing a small c or c++ program to do this, but I haven't been able to find a way to do that either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `lsof /dev/video0` should find the process which has the webcam (the first webcam should default to /dev/video0 but if you have more then one you may have a /dev/video1 /dev/video2 and so on, also some errors may cause 0 to be skipped).`

Comment: This worked great, thank you! `lsof -t /dev/video0` returns the PID of whatever is accessing the camera.

Comment: It is strange.
Has result of ...
WARNING: can't stat() aufs file system /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/xxxx

Comment: On a PC running Lubuntu 18.04.6 LTS with IP cameras, the path /dev does not list any folder named video or any combination videoX where X=0,1,2,... I tried lsof | grep video but I think an IP camera does not get installed within the kernel as a device so it would not be under /dev/

Answer (score 0):

Video devices in Linux are accessed using v4l interface(Video 4 Linux). There's a library and a command line tool called `v4l2-ctl` in the **v4l-utils** package. However, I don't think there's a way to tell if a process is recording from it, just whether a process is connected, as described by @RomanA.Taycher

Comment: v4l2-ctl --list-devices will list all USB cameras using Linux drivers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video4Linux). It will not list an IP camera and it will not tell if a program is connected to it. These devices will be listed as device files under /dev as /dev/video0, /dev/video1., etc